# Not A Statement Error When Instantiating Class in Main Method

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
  private Map<String,Integer> map;

  public MyClass() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("foo", 1);
    map.put("bar", 3);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi");
    MyClass class = new MyClass(); 
  }
}
```

I am getting a "not a statement" error at `MyClass class = new MyClass();` but I can't figure out why. Can someone point out the issue please?

Comment: Don't use "class" as an object name. Rename it to something else

Comment: In Java `class` is a keyword and cannot be used as a variable name.

Comment: `class` is a reserved word, so you can't use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use "class" as an object name. Rename it to something else.

`class` is a keyword, so compiler is expecting the name of a class after it (To be more exact, it is expecting complete valid declaration of a class). Therefore, it cannot define your line as a valid statement.

[List of words that you cannot use as variables' names.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)